Are mind and body separate entities?
When I try to commit suicide, I back off. My brain wants to die, my body resists. What hope does my body see that my brain cannot? Why one resists the other?
Maybe my body wants to die a painless death?

Both a dualist and a monist can commit suicide. Hope you come up with the best approach for resolving any issues..

It's not your brain that wants to die, it is your ego. Become master of yourself.

Get professional help. At the very least, talk to somebody. Right now.

Is it your body resisting the act of suicide or your soul? Homicide is a great wrong, whether the murderer and the victim are different people or one and the same. Maybe what you are experiencing is a spiritual revelation telling you that what you contemplate is evil. I don't know what has led you to contemplate this solution to your problems, but I can tell you that there are better solutions if you will only search for them. Sometimes the solution is drastic: you have to make drastic changes to your life and just remove yourself from an intolerable situation. More often, the solution is less drastic but more profound and more difficult: you have to change yourself to tolerate what you currently find intolerable. Although this second solution is more difficult, it is also more rewarding, just as any form of growth is rewarding.
If your intolerable situation involves anger or hate, try forgiveness. The power of forgiveness is enormous and it can do great good for both the wrong-doer and the wronged. Understand that all human beings do wrong, and if we all had to pay for all the wrongs we do, our punishment would last our whole life.
If your intolerable situation involves guilt, try forgiving yourself. If possible, the first step should be to make amends and ask forgiveness of those you have wronged, but whether they forgive you or not, once you have done whatever you can to make the situation right, then forgive yourself and put the guilt aside.
If your intolerable situation involves envy, lack of something you want, or lack of being something that you want to be, then try loving yourself. Accept yourself for who and what you are just as you would accept a loved family member who is what you are. Don't dwell on what you want, and instead dwell on what is good.
Love, acceptance, and forgiveness will go much further to solve all of the problems of the human condition than any philosophy ever will.
I wish you the best.
